# Error run a application in eclipse after update Kotlin in Intellij

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, kotlin, intellij-idea

I have a Kotlin and Spring Boot application that I developed in eclipse; The last change I remember making is updating Kotlin in IntelliJ and now when I try to run my application in Eclipse the console shows me the following error:

```
No Location
    EXCEPTION: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.openapi.util.text.StringUtil.internEmptyString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.cache.TypeInfo.internFrequentType(TypeInfo.java:269)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.<init>(ClsJavaCodeReferenceElementImpl.java:49)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsAnnotationImpl$1.compute(ClsAnnotationImpl.java:47)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsAnnotationImpl$1.compute(ClsAnnotationImpl.java:40)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.AtomicNotNullLazyValue.getValue(AtomicNotNullLazyValue.java:37)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.compiled.ClsAnnotationImpl.getNameReferenceElement(ClsAnnotationImpl.java:106)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.JavaAnnotationImpl.resolvePsi(JavaAnnotationImpl.java:84)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.JavaAnnotationImpl.getClassId(JavaAnnotationImpl.java:51)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.JavaElementsKt$buildLazyValueForMap$1.invoke(javaElements.kt:65)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.JavaElementsKt$buildLazyValueForMap$1.invoke(javaElements.kt)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.JavaPackageImpl.getAnnotationsByFqName(JavaPackageImpl.kt)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.MapBasedJavaAnnotationOwner$DefaultImpls.findAnnotation(javaElements.kt:59)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.structure.impl.JavaPackageImpl.findAnnotation(JavaPackageImpl.kt:25)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.components.JavaAnnotationMapper.findMappedJavaAnnotation(JavaAnnotationMapper.kt:72)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.LazyJavaAnnotations.iterator(LazyJavaAnnotations.kt:40)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.ContextKt.computeNewDefaultTypeQualifiers(context.kt:245)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.ContextKt$childForClassOrPackage$1.invoke(context.kt:223)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.load.java.lazy.ContextKt$childForClassOrPackage$1.invoke(context.kt)
    at kotlin.UnsafeLazyImpl.getValue(Lazy.kt:81)
```

And it ends with the message:
`Error: Could not find or load main class Main mx.job.project.config.AplicacionConfigKt`

Thank you!!

Comment: The Java path is apparently set correctly in Eclipse and works correctly (executing a "Hello world" does not throw errors).
I have reinstalled Eclipse, Java, IntelliJ and it has not worked.
I downloaded the project again from Git and it doesn't work.
Any ideas?

Comment: No, the project does not work in intelliJ or Eclipse, but I have returned to the commit where it did. So I have discarded that it is the project, if not some configuration which I have not noticed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had installed **Eclipse(2020-03)** and **Kotlin plugin (0.8.20)**, and I received a error when I execute my project.

I solved it When I uninstalled the Kotlin plugin 0.8.20 and installed 0.8.19, I believe it is a bug in kotlin plugin for eclipse.

https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/kotlin/eclipse-plugin/

Comment: Thank you very much, it has worked for me.
I describe how to install it in case it is useful for someone.
To install a plugin from a URL go to _Help > Install New Software_,  paste the URL in the _Work with_ section and proceed with the installation.

Answer (score 4):

First of all I have closed all my projects.
Then I have uninstalled Kotlin Plugin for Eclise at the Eclipse Marketplace site. An then installed previous Version old-fashioned way by using an update site directly:

https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/kotlin/eclipse-plugin/0.8.19/

After I have restarted Eclipse all was right again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a project with Spring Boot + Kotlin (some controllers/mappers/classes in Java and others in Kotlin) and after trying a lot of approaches, the only that worked was to use Eclipse 03-2020 + Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse V0.8.19.