# Having issues with "Building web applications with Spring Boot and Kotlin" spring official documentation example

Tags: spring, kotlin

### **Coding Environment**

- Spring Tool Suite 4 **4.3.2.RELEASE**

- Spring Boot **2.3.1.RELEASE**

- Java **1.8.0_171**

- Kotlin **1.3.72**

- Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse **0.8.20**

- Maven **3.3.9**

I wanted to convert my entire spring boot(**Java**) module to **Kotlin**. I was familiar with kotlin by going through kotlin documentation. I started spring boot with kotlin tutorial available at https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-kotlin/ by creating a new sample spring boot app wih Kotlin and Maven as build tool. Added only webmvc starter for simplicity. when i run the app without creating any **@RestController**'s or **@Controller**'s, the app is run successfully on specified port. after that i tried to add RestController(Controller also added,but same issue). then the issue came(thought it would work fine as it did in official sping boot with kotlin docs,but it did not.) and i found 2 consoles are active.

- Normal Console(where we check logs)

- JetBrains Console(**org.jetbrains.kotlin.ui.console**)

with or without issue,the normal console is showing the logs like always it does i.e showing port number on which the app is run etc and jet brains console is blank(i.e no issues)
but with the issue,jet brains console is showing the error

**No Location

EXCEPTION: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intellij.openapi.util.text.StringUtil.internEmptyString(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;**

googled it and got no solution for this  error. below are code snippets of Main Configuration and RestController classes.if any one faced this kind of issue,please help me solve this

### **KotlinDemoApplication.kt**

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class KotlinDemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<KotlinDemoApplication>(*args)
}
```

### **GreetingController.kt**

```
@RestController
class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greet")
    fun greet() = "Kella Vivek"
}
```

your help or suggestion is very much appriciated.

Comment: Try Kotlin Plugin for Eclipse 0.8.19 instead of 0.8.20 (c.f. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60743746/error-run-a-application-in-eclipse-after-update-kotlin-in-intellij)

Comment: Thanks for your response @Edgar. I have tried downgrading 0.8.20 to 0.8.19 but issue still persists and i have tried different other versions also like 0.8.2,0.8.8,0.8.9 and etc.. nothing worked for STS 4 and Eclipse 2020-06,2020-03. shifted to IntelliJ IDEA and it worked perfectly without causing any issues. so for the time being i will stick to Intellij IDEA and once again thanks for your response.